# search for services in a local wifi network

Tags: android, service

i want to list all local services which are connected to my local wifi.
This services should be listet on my android phone and get automatically updatet if somethig was changed in time. Has anybody a working code example or a good link?
thx

Answer (score 0):

All you had to do is to go to the [developer.android.com](http://developer.android.com) and search it...

http://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/nsd-wifi-direct.html

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer. I thought i have to use something like bonjour for ios?

Comment: I need something zeroconf.

Comment: I don't know any zeroconf for Android , but bonjour got an extension for java as i remember .
take a look at this link :
http://www.panda-os.com/2014/08/implement-zeroconf-android/#.VZlRUvmqpBc

Comment: If it solved/helped with your issue you can vote up :)